# Draw indicators in five minutes interval in a clock

Tags: javascript, math, html5-canvas

I'm learning canvas, and I'm trying to draw a clock..

By now, [I have this](http://jsfiddle.net/8mwh52g9/):

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = 100;
canvas.height = 100;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

if (!canvas.getContext) {
    console.log("Good morning! .. Please check your canvas");
}
else {
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var path = new Path2D();

    // outer border
    path.moveTo(100,50);
    path.arc(50,50,50,0,Math.PI*2,true);

    // inner border
    path.moveTo(97,50);
    path.arc(50,50,47,0,Math.PI*2,true);

    // indicators: fifteen in fifteen minutes
    path.lineTo(90,50);
    path.moveTo(3,50);
    path.lineTo(10,50);
    path.moveTo(50,3);
    path.lineTo(50,10);
    path.moveTo(50,97);
    path.lineTo(50,90);

    // show canvas
    ctx.stroke(path);
}
```

As you can see, I drawed the indicators one by one (in fifteen minutes interval).

I'd like to draw it in interval of *five minutes* ..

Is there any *genial for-loop/mathematic* to do this?

Thanks for your time.

---

Edit: just to [share the result](http://codepen.io/WashingtonGuedes/pen/qdxgGK).

Comment: This article (especially part III) should point you in the right direction ... http://www.w3schools.com/canvas/canvas_clock_face.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need some trigonometrics and a for-loop for this.

You might know that a circle is defined as all points like P(cos(x),sin(x)).
In this case the x value in the sin and cos functions has to be calculated as follows:

```
x=50+50*Math.cos((i/numticks)*2*Math.PI)
```

So what does all this mean?

- The first 50 moves the circle to the center of the canvas.
- (i/numticks) scales the number of ticks to a range from 0 to 1

then we multiply all this by 2*Pi and that gives the argument for the sin and cos.

```
var numticks=12
for(var i = 0;i <= numticks;i++) {
   path.moveTo(50+50*Math.cos((i/numticks)*2*Math.PI),50+50*Math.sin((i/numticks)*2*Math.PI));
   path.lineTo(50+45*Math.cos((i/numticks)*2*Math.PI),50+45*Math.sin((i/numticks)*2*Math.PI));
}
```